# Only first row from a specific Column with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complicated SQL Query that returns about 10 000 rows. In my query i have a OrderNr and a lot of rows contains the same OrderNr. Now i want to grab only the first 1 of the rows with the same OrderNr. This is only for the OrderNr column and not for any other column. I mean i have same values in some other columns also but there i want all the rows.

Here i made some easy example for you

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07780/4)

Goal is too get the output

```
1,Bruno,Dan
2,Johnson,Lars
4,Jordan, Derreck
5,Johnson,Peter
```

Here is Firstname the same as my OrderNr

How do i do this?

Comment: You have to use `DISTINCT` and specify ordering with `ORDER BY` to tell the database which row you would like to return.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I would love to see how that is done. I doubt it is possible, please prove me wrong

Comment: @t-clausen.dk it seems like this is not possible using SQL Server. Too bad it doesn't support `DISTINCT ON`.

Answer (score 9):

You can partition by orderNumbers and rank the orders by ids. When selecting only rows with rownumber 1, you get the expected result.

```
;WITH orders AS (
     SELECT *, 
        Row_Number() over (PARTITION BY OrderNr ORDER BY <ID>) rn       
    FROM T  
)
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE rn=1
```

With your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07780/11

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName,
  row_number() over (partition by Firstname order by PersonID) rn
  FROM Persons
)
SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p1
where p1.PersonID = (select min(PersonID) from persons p2 where p2.firstname=p1.firstname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the expected result using two steps, without `CTEs` and `WINDOW FUNCTIONs`.

First step: `GROUP` your rows by `FirstName` and choose a minimum `PersonID` for each of them

Second step: Use a `self-join` to get `LastName` value for that minimum `PersonId` we obtained in step first.

```
SELECT foo.PersonID, b.LastName, foo.FirstName
FROM(
  SELECT 
    MIN(PersonID) AS PersonID,
    FirstName 
  FROM Persons 
  GROUP BY FirstName
  ) foo
  INNER JOIN Persons b ON foo.PersonID = b.PersonID
```